# Android Studio: Alignment

Tags: android, android-studio, alignment

I've a problem with alignment a webview and an AdView in Android Studio:

What I want to get, is the ad at the bottom and all over it the webview. However, I am not able to resize the webwiev to start from the top. At the moment, the webview is just as big as the website is, as you can see here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkj00jnck049kqm/Unbenannt.png

Here's my xml layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/ad_view"
            />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`  in your **`AdView`**

SAMPLE CODE

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view" in webview in above xml code

Comment: For getting better user experience i will suggest to add it else WebView and Google Ads views mix up.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the changes as below in your current code

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">


  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
      android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view"
      />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/ad_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
      />

  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```